# How to concatenate swift string with NSLineSeparatorCharacter constant

Tags: swift, string, unicode

I am trying to concatenate unicode character to existing string using existing constant `NSLineSeparatorCharacter` /`NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter`. I don't want code which has a \u{2029} printed.

```
let paragraphSeparator = "\u{2029}"
let paragraphSeparatorCharacter = NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter
let content1 = "Receipt" + paragraphSeparator
let content2 = "Receipt" + String(paragraphSeparatorCharacter) //INCORRECT: Receipt8233
```

Haven't seen example how to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to initialize string with `Unicode.Scalar`

```
let paragraphSeparatorCharacter = String(Unicode.Scalar(NSLineSeparatorCharacter)!)
let content = "Receipt" + paragraphSeparatorCharacter + "Receipt"
```